# Can krumo() and PHP ActiveRecord work together in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpactiverecord, krumo

UPDATE: Krumo seems to be outdated, and I discovered [Kint](https://github.com/raveren/kint), which does everything I wanted out of Krumo.

I started a CI site that uses PHP ActiveRecord. Please note: PHP ActiveRecord is **not** the same as CI ActiveRecord.

ActiveRecord works great; more than I hoped for.

I then added Krumo, which also works great, sometimes; Krumo works properly unless I run Krumo on an ActiveRecord object.

```
print_r($this->user); // Works
krumo($this->user); // Does not work
```

The output for the krumo() call is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\UndefinedPropertyException' with message 'Undefined property: User_model->krumo50afd2e8f24af in /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php on line 514' in /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php:514 Stack trace: #0 /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php(333): ActiveRecord\Model->read_attribute('krumo50afd2e8f2...') #1 /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/application/libraries/krumo/Krumo.php(951): ActiveRecord\Model->__get('krumo50afd2e8f2...') #2 /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/application/libraries/krumo/Krumo.php(1104): krumo::_vars(Object(User_model)) #3 /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/application/libraries/krumo/Krumo.php(789): krumo::_object(Object(User_model), '...') #4 /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/application/libraries/krumo/Krumo.php(584): krumo::_dump(Object(User_model)) #5 [internal function]: krumo::dump(Object(User_model)) #6 /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/application/librarie in /Users/ted/Sites/cnc/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php on line 514
```

It would be wonderful if I could get these two to work together. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just went through description, looks like you can just use `xdebug` it would nicely color output your regular `var_dump`;

Looks also like krumo is outdated and unsupported. I would not use such a library

Comment: Thanks! I am considering xdebug. I upvoted, but want to hold off on accepting the answer in case someone knows how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks. I took your advice (to avoid the outdated library), did some research, and I now happily using kint. Modern and powerful.